# What scenario would create an nosuchelementexception with nextLine()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The documentation for `nextLine()` says that it can throw a `nosuchelementexception`. But when using the `nextLine()` to get input for the Scanner as demonstrated in the following code, the `nosuchelementexception` is not thrown, The only thing that happens is by pressing "Enter" two times the programs just ends. I submitted the same code for an evaluation to an online system, there also the system said that the code throws a `nosuchelementexception`

What sort of an input would produce a `nosuchelementexception`?

```
String input = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

input += sc.nextLine() + " ";
input += sc.nextLine() + " ";

System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: This will happen if you've previously closed any scanner that uses System.in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an example where the standard input (i.e. `System.in`) is piped from another application:

```sh
echo 'one line only' | java Read
```

Or read from a file:

```sh
java Read <file_with_one_line.txt
```

Or using interactive user input:

```sh
java Read
```

```
I am entering one line
Ctrl+D
```

These examples assume that you’ve compiled the code you’ve posted (wrapped into a class `Read`) to `Read.class` in the same directory.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        input += sc.nextLine() + " ";
        input += sc.nextLine() + " ";

        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

```sh
javac read.java
```

Comment: @Varuna Ctrl+D It signals [end-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to the terminal. Its purpose is to end interactive input that is being sent to the standard input of an application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible when reading files:

I created a new txt-file without any content (test.txt) in it and ran the following code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

---

**Edit**

It can also appear with System.in because when closing one scanner it appears to also close System.in.

Consider the following code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        sc2.nextLine();
    }
}
```

This throws the following exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

This happens because `sc` (with access to `System.in`) was closed. This causes that `System.in` is not accessible anymore and therefore `sc2` doesn't work properly and throws an exception.

Comment: @Varuna I just updated the answer. Does this answer the question?

Comment: No it doesn't. The input stream has to be System.in, not a file

Comment: @Varuna `System.in` is the *standard input stream*. It does not in general (and, for that matter, it doesn’t *usually*) read interactively. It reads from whatever stream is piped into your application. And if that stream ends and you try to read from it, `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

Comment: @PhilippWilhelm It’s true for *any* stream that ends, not just for files.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph " It does not in general (and, for that matter, it doesn’t usually) read interactively. It reads from whatever stream is piped into your application" Can you please explain in detail. What do you mean by "It does not in general (and, for that matter, it doesn’t usually) read interactively". and " It reads from whatever stream is piped into your application" ?

Comment: @Varuna I just added another code snippet that throws the exception when working with System.in.

Comment: @Varuna See my answer for examples.

Comment: @Philipp Wilhelm After the execution of sc.nextLine() has finished, you close the System,in using the sc.close(). Why does that throw the NoSuchElementException? If the sc.close() results in exception, how do you explain that?

Comment: @Varuna The doesn't appear on line 9, but on line 10:  `sc2.nextLine();`. The program tries to access `System.in`, but that's not possible (because it was "closed", together with `sc`) and therefore the program throws an exception.

Comment: @Philipp Wilhelm As you say sc2.nextLine() is trying to access System.in and as a result the NoSuchElementException is thrown. But sc2 is open.If sc2.nextLine() throws the NoSuchElementException then as you say so should sc.nextLine(). isn't it?

Comment: @Varuna Yes it is, but System.in is not accessible anymore because one scanner with access to System.in was closed. That's why sc2 doesn't work properly and throws an exception.